# Vertical align seems to affect position of a sibling element

Tags: html, css

Caveat, I'm very unfamiliar with CSS. I'm probably misusing `vertical-align`. I made this very simple example of a problem which I ran into. In the following snippetsI apply `vertical-align` to Block 1, however it is block 2 which gets centered. (Snippet two has `vertical-align` removed to see the effect.)

Why exactly is happening?

```html
<div style="background-color: gray; height:200px;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background:green; height:200px; vertical-align:middle">Block 1</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background:red">Block 2</div>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="background-color: gray; height:200px;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background:green; height:200px;">Block 1</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background:red">Block 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect vertical align to work on an element that has the exact same height as its parent?

Comment: normally you use vertical align for the items in a div where the div has `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @xmaster You mean the parent div has should be an inline-block?

Comment: @Jay Except it doesn't. I'm referring to block 2. My question is why a CSS property set for block 1 is affecting block 2. But let me check other links for possible duplicates.

Comment: @huggie yes thats what i meant

Comment: OK the `Vertical-align aligns everything else except self` explains it for me. Thanks.